# Input box key Up Check (Validation)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

my array

```
var foo = {};
    foo['xarr'] = [ "23" ];
    foo['yarr'] = [ "21","21","22","23","24"];
    foo['zarr']= [ "70","71","72","73","74","75" ];
```

Input box takes maximum 4 character and i have a array object 
i want when a user enter first tow character and it matches from the array i want to add a class on a div.
if it matches from foo['xarr'] add some diffrent class,when it matches from foo['yarr'] add some diffrent class and so on.

my html markup:

```
<li class="Images">
    <div>
        <input type="text" name="cnumber1" class="inputBx" style="width:58px;" maxlength="4" size="4"/>            
    </div>
    <span class="test"></span>
</li>
```

Java Script

I was trying through this way but didnt get any success

```
$('.inputBx').keydown(function() {
         var inputVal = $(this).val(),
             iLen = inputVal.length;
             if( iLen >= 2){
                for(var key in foo) {
                  if( foo[key].indexOf(inputVal) >= 0){
                      if(foo[key] == 'xarr' )
                          $('.Images .test ').addClass('fullOpactiy');
                      if(foo[key] == 'yarr' )
                          $('.cardImages .test ').addClass('fullOpactiy');
                      if(foo[key] == 'zarr' )
                          $('.Images .test ').addClass('fullOpactiy');
                  }
                }
             }
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

Something I don't understand in your code :

```
for(var key in foo) {
    if( foo[key].indexOf(inputVal) >= 0){
       if(foo[key] == 'xarr' ){
            //...
       }
    }
}
```

key is in foo object, so it's either xarr, yarr or zarr. Then foo[key] is a number array (which makes correct your sentence `foo[key].indexOf(inputVal) >= 0`). Why `foo[key]` would ever be equals to the string 'xarr', or 'yarr'?
I suggest this correction before continuing your research :

```
for(var key in foo) {
    var idx = foo[key].indexOf(inputVal); //search in the array
    if(  idx >= 0){
       if(key == 'yarr'){
            $('.cardImages .test ').addClass('fullOpactiy');
       }
       else{
          $('.Images .test ').addClass('fullOpacity');  
       }
       return true;//ends your search now, no need to continue
    }
}
```

I think this matching algorithm is suboptimal, but it should work

cheers

Grooveek

Answer (score 0):

this works for me here is a[working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mcgrailm/yJ66t/)

```
var foo = [];
foo['xarr'] = ["23"];
foo['yarr'] = ["21", "21", "22", "23", "24"];
foo['zarr'] = ["70", "71", "72", "73", "74", "75"];


$('.inputBx').keyup(function() {
    var inputVal = this.value;
    iLen = inputVal.length;
    if (iLen >= 2) {
        if ($.inArray(inputVal, foo['xarr']) >= 0) {
            $('.Images, .test').addClass('fullOpactiy')
        }
        if ($.inArray(inputVal, foo['yarr']) >= 0) {
            $('.cardImages, .test').addClass('fullOpactiy')
        }
        if ($.inArray(inputVal, foo['zarr']) >=0) {
            $('.Images, .test').addClass('fullOpactiy')
        }
    }
});
```